# Blink to highlight screen painting (like Quartz Debug) on Linux/X11

Tags: linux, quartz-graphics, repaint

I am looking for a tool similar to OS X’s [Quartz Debug](http://guides.macrumors.com/Quartz_Debug) for Linux (well, a Gnome desktop on X). QD will blink up a yellow box that stays on the screen for one second on top of any area of the screen that is repainted.

Very useful to identify unnecessary repaints. Can anyone suggest such a tool for Linux?